# Which document is required when spouse is an advocate for non-ecr category?

Tags: indian-citizens, passport-renewals

I am applying for reissue of my Indian passport. My spouse is an advocate and thus I can apply for passport without "Emigration Check Required" endorsement (called non-ecr). What document am I required to upload on passport website for re-issue of passport for non-ecr category in my case? Professional degree or id card from bar council of advocate?

Comment: What country is this about?

Comment: @JorenVandamme ECR is usually associated with indian passports

Answer (score 2):

As per [Indian passport website](https://portal2.passportindia.gov.in/AppOnlineProject/onlineHtml/NonEcrDocuments.html), you need to upload the following:

- A copy of spouse degree
- An attested copy of your marriage certificate
- Your name must be endorsed in your spouse passport

To quote from the page

> All professional Degree holders , their spouses and dependent children. Examples of professional degree holders are Doctors holding MBBS degree or equivalent degree in AYURVED or HOMEOPATHY, accredited Journalists, Engineers, Chartered Accountants, Cost Accountants, Lecturers, Teachers, Scientists, Advocates, etc
>
> **Certificate of the professional degree held.**
>
> **For spouses, certificate signifying relation** - An attested copy of marriage certificate issued by the Marriage Registrar needs to be submitted. For verification, **spouse's name needs to be endorsed in the applicant's passport**.

However, you can get a Non ECR passport of your own if you fulfill any of following (from same linked page):

- Have passed matriculation or higher examination (Need a copy of your degree)
- Have paid income tax (Need copy of last return)
- Are above 50 years of age (Need your birth certificate)